# How to display a dialog box on clicking the button of another dialog box?

Tags: android

Am doing my android project. I have created the dialog box with YES and NO button. If i click YES a new dialog box should be displayed with options to select. I created the dialog box with options. But couldnt display it when i click YES in the dialog box which i created first. How can i do it? Please help. 
Thanks.

Here is the code of the dialog box which i created. When i click YES button in this dialog i should display another dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Low Memory\nYou want to send the file to server?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                   }
               });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What is the problem ? Does the logcat show some errors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Low Memory\nYou want to send the file to server?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(CLASSNAME.this);
                    builder2.setTitle("hi!");
                    //etc
                    builder2.show();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                     finish();
                }
            });
     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.show();
```

Hope this helps. ;)

Comment: Should i put this inside the onClick function of a button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("Are you absolutely positively sure?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                   }
               });
        final AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();




        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Low Memory\nYou want to send the file to server?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       alert1.show();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog1,alertDialog2;

     public  void  showAlertDialog1(String title,String message,final Context context)
            {
             alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
             alertDialog1.setTitle(title);
             alertDialog1.setMessage(message);
             alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                  errorAlertDialog2("second AlertDialog","second AlertDialog",context)

                }
             });
             alertDialog1.show();
            }




         public  void  showAlertDialog2(String title,String message,Context context)
            {
             alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
             alertDialog2.setTitle(title);
             alertDialog2.setMessage(message);
             alertDialog2.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                  alertDialog2.dismiss();
                }
             });
             alertDialog2.show();
            }
```